# SQLで列の値がNullではない列の値を表示する

Tags: sql

SQLを勉強しております。初歩的なことかもしれませんが、アドバイスをいただけませんでしょうか。

```
Item ID, small_category, mid_category, large_category
332, ルアー, 釣具, スポーツ
445, ソフト, 据え置きゲーム, ホビー
551, 野球, スポーツ, NULL, NULL
661, ホビー, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

このようなデータがあったときに、
どのItem IDにおいてはも一番最大のカテゴリを表示したい場合はどのようなSQLが必要でしょうか。

期待するアウトプット

```
Item ID, catgory
332, スポーツ
445, ホビー
551, スポーツ
661, ホビー
```

下記のようなコードを作って実行すると、

```
Item ID,
CASE
        WHEN mid_category = NULL THEN small_category
        WHEN large_cateogry = NULL THEN mid_category
        ELSE large_category
        END as category
```

結果

```
Item ID, catgory
332, スポーツ
445, ホビー
551, NULL
661, NULL
```

このような結果になってしまいました。
上記コードだとlarge_categoryが無いケースだとうまくいきましたが、
Categoryの階層が増えるとうまくいきませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLは他のプログラミング言語と少し異なります。
まず論理値は`TRUE` / `FALSE`の2値論理ではなく、`TRUE` / `FALSE` / `UNKNOWN`の[3値論理](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/3%E5%80%A4%E8%AB%96%E7%90%86)となっています。その上で、[SQLにおける`NULL`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null#SQL%E3%81%AENULL)も異なり、`NULL`との比較は全て`UNKNOWN`になります。
そのため、

```
mid_category = NULL
```

は常に`UNKNOWN`であり、`TRUE`ではないため不成立と判断されます。`NULL`であるかを比較するために`IS`演算子が用意されており、

```
Item ID,
CASE
        WHEN mid_category IS NULL THEN small_category
        WHEN large_cateogry IS NULL THEN mid_category
        ELSE large_category
        END as category
```

と記述するとよいでしょう。（この順で比較したいかは質問者さんの判断に任せます。）

Comment: sayuriさん　非常に初歩的な部分を見逃しておりました。ご指摘いただきありがとうございました。